# PC can't recover from "Turn off display after 5 mins"

Tags: windows-7, freeze, bsod, sleep, wake-up

My power settings is set to turn off display after 5mins. Occasionally my PC can't seem to wake up from this. The monitor is just black with its led indicator blinking. The keyboard and mouse's lights are on but the Caps Lock's led indicator is not working. It appears to have hangged. This happens once in a while.

Other issues that might be related:

- Occasional BSOD
- Firefox crashes once in a while too

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Is only the monitor sleeping or the whole PC?  What does Event Viewer show?

Comment: What BSOD error code do you get?

Comment: @ernie not sure what info should I look for at the Event Viewer

Comment: @yassarikhan786 I will record it next time and update it here.

Comment: If the system "hangs" as described, after restarting the system, I'd check Event Viewer to see if there were any errors before the restart.

Comment: @ernie I see one Error message "The previous system shutdown at 10:17:31 PM on ‎9/‎19/‎2013 was unexpected." but before that there is no error. I think that error was generated by me hitting the restart button when the system hangged as I described.